# Flutter firebase database plugin example project not building for android

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, flutter

I'm working on a flutter project that uses firebase real-time database. The project works seamlessly for iOS, but doesn't build for android, although I've followed the guide.

When building the project for android, I am facing the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':firebase_core:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core'
```

I downloaded the official plugin example at github code as-is, and tried to build their example project. The same error occurs.

Is anyone able to build the following project for android?
[Github Flutter Firebase Database Example Project](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/firebase_database/example). If anyone succeeds to build it, I would be very grateful in showing me how.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: That's not how Stack Overflow works. If you're having problems getting a project to build, show the [minimal, complete, verifiable code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of how to reproduce that problem in your question itself.

Comment: You're right, thank you. I'll take that into consideration in my future posts :)

Answer (score 1):

The main problem was that when I was compiling the android project, I was doing so by opening the android folder in flutter project and not the main flutter project folder.

The solution was simple but subtle.

1. change the android package name to match that specified in firebase
2. follow the google guide of firebase setup for firebase android part
3. build the project by opening the main flutter folder (project's root folder) and not the android project folder. (this is the subtle step I was missing)

Just for reference, I had to add 2 parts of code for the project's root build.gradle file for it to build:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    // ...
    // ...
    // ... 

    // add the following line 
    maven {
      url 'https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools'
    }
  }
}
// ...
// ...
// ... 

// add the following snippet 
subprojects {
  project.configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency {
      details - >
        if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support' &&
          !details.requested.name.contains('multidex')) {
          details.useVersion "27.1.1"
        }
    }
  }
}
```